# Laravel 4 Login-template issue

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build my first website in laravel 4.2 and I'm doing the site login. After the user submits his username and password the link to the website home doesn't work. I think that there is a problem with the template that I'm using, but don't know for sure and I've been stuck in this for a couple of days already. I know this may be very basic, but as I was  saying before is my first time using Laravel.
The AuthController function for the post:

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $data = [

        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    ];       
    if (Auth::attempt($data, Input::get('remember')))
    {
        return Redirect::intended('home');
    }

    return Redirect::back()->with('error_message', 'Invalid data')->withInput();
}
```

My route.php:

```
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@postLogin');

Route::group(['before' => 'auth'], function(){

    Route::get('home', function(){
        return View::make('site/index');
    });
    Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logOut');
});
```

And in my login view this is what I use:

```
<form  action="login" method="post" class="p-t-15">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{  csrf_token() }}">
```

Hope you can help me, thanks :)

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: When hit the submit, it loads the same login view, it doesn't go to the home.
(Sorry for my english)

Comment: Have you checked after clicking submit your form is being submitted to the postLogin() function. you can try to debug this by writing `Log::info('email -
 '.Input::get('email'));` and `Log::info('password - '.Input::get('password'));` and check laravel.log file see if your submitted email and password is being submitted to that function or not.

Comment: This is what it say in the log:
[2017-01-29 18:07:03] production.INFO: email - user@gmail.com [] []
[2017-01-29 18:07:03] production.INFO: password - password [] []

Comment: great. please be patience. it means you form is being submitted correctly. I am just trying to divide the problem in small crunch and trying to figure that where is the problem in your code. just do one step more. just replace your code `return Redirect::intended('home');` with `return "logged in successfully";`  and outside the if block just replace `return Redirect::back()->with('error_message', 'Invalid data')->withInput();` with `return "login error;"`. it will clear that where is the actual problem. please tell me the output.

Comment: I get login error!!
Thank you so much for your help  :')

Comment: ok. Are you sure your email id and password is correct what you have putted while registering the user ? If yes then once try removing second argument from attempt method. i mean remove `Input::get('remember')` and try

Comment: Thank you, now it's working, I add a new user (to see if the user credentials were the error) and also remove that line that you said and now I get "logged in successfully"
Thank you so much!!  :')

Comment: Glad to help @nbravos :). i think the problem was with remembering user. your `Input::get('remember')` was not giving you the correct value. you can always pass the second argument of input as true if you want. you can write this `Input::get('remember', true);`. please make all your redirect correct :)

Comment: Why are you using Laravel version 4???

Comment: I installed it and started using it for my application, now it's too late to update (is not late, I just don't want to change my code -_- )